# Symfony not respecting overriding class argument for test environment

Tags: symfony

I have a bundle with a `services.yml` where the service definition uses a parameter contained within the same file for the `class` parameter, like so:

```
parameters:
    application.servicename.class: Application\Service\ServiceName

services:
    application.servicename:
        class: %application.servicename.class%
```

Now I want to override the service class for my test environment. However, overriding the parameter in `config_test.yml` does not result in an object of the overriding class being instantiated.

Adding the following to `config_test.yml`:

```
parameters:
    application.servicename.class: Application\Mock\Service\ServiceName
```

...still causes the service to be instantieted from `Application\Service\ServiceName`. If I try passing `application.servicename.class` as an argument to the service and dump it in the constructor, the overriden value of `Application\Mock\Service\ServiceName` is displayed.

Why is Symfony not respecting the overridden value for the service class when preparing the service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, this problem was not related to Symfony loading configuration but rather an assumption that the incorrect class was loaded. This assumption was caused by the fact that the method calls of both the original service (and the mock extending it) was marked as private.

Had this not been a problem, I belive what I was attempting to do should be possible, ref http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/bundles/override.html#services-configuration

Sorry to waste your time.

Answer (score 2):

You should move

```
parameters:
application.servicename.class: Application\Service\ServiceName
```

From services.yml to config.yml becasuse in my opninion you are overriding the value of the paremeter in config_test.yml with the value you have in services.yml

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a Extension class in your Bundle:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html

I think you might be able to change priorities loading the config files
Here's an example of implementation

```
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container {

    $configuration = new Configuration();
    $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);
    $container->setParameter('your.config.parameter', $config['your']['config']['parameter']);

    $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/config'));
    $loader->load('services.yml');

}
```